# LC-3 Assembly Accessing Array Values

Tags: arrays, assembly, instruction-set, lc3

I was given an array, defined by:

```
.orig x6000
.fill -20
.fill 14
.fill 7
.fill 0
.fill -3
.fill 11
.fill 9
.fill -9
.fill 2
.fill -5
.end
```

I need to iterate through these values within my main program. From what I understand this "array" is just values stored in memory far away from where the instructions are stored. My question is, "How do I load these values?" I know that they start at `x6000`, but I don't know how to get to them using instructions.

Comment: You probably need `LEA` and `LDR` instructions, see [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29811159/547981).

Answer (score 2):

**The best thing to do would be to read [the LC3 ISA](http://highered.mheducation.com/sites/dl/free/0072467509/104653/PattPatelAppA.pdf) and pay special attention to the `LDR` instruction.**

Here is an example program to help get you started.

You need to know and keep track of two things: (1) the address of the array and (2) the length of the array/index as you iterate. For (1), I chose to use a filled value; for (2) the length of the array is defined in the instruction itself. I `AND R1, R1, 0` to clear the register and add `10`. We could just as easily have a filled value `LENGTH` equal to `10` and `LD R1 LENGTH`.

The loop begins by decrementing `R1` and checking to see if it is negative. If `R1` is negative, then the loop exits. We decremented length first, so you can think of the "length" (value in `R1`) as an index. So, if the index < 0, then the loop exits.

The `LDR R0, R2, 0` instruction gets the value at the address in register `R2` offset by `0` and puts it in `R0`. Presumably you would want to do something with the data after this line.

Before the unconditional branch to `LOOP`, we increment the address of the array to point at the next element.

```
.orig x3000

LD R2, ARRAY        ; R2 = x6000
AND R1, R1, 0       ; R1 = 0 (clear before add)
ADD R1, R1, 10      ; R1 = 10 (length of array)
LOOP ADD R1, R1, -1 ; R1--
BRn DONE            ; if R1 < 0 then halt, else...
LDR R0, R2, 0       ; R0 <-- mem[R2 + 0]
ADD R2, R2, 1       ; R2++
BR LOOP             ; loop
DONE HALT           ; halt

ARRAY   .fill x6000

.orig x6000
.fill -20
.fill 14
.fill 7
.fill 0
.fill -3
.fill 11
.fill 9
.fill -9
.fill 2
.fill -5
.end
```